# Download CPAN Repository. No Linux System with Internet Access

Tags: perl, centos, repository, cpan

our Linux Systems have no Internet Access. 
Only Windows Clients have Internet Access.
I want to build a offline CPAN Repository.

I can't download each Module an picking all the dependencies. 
Is there a way to download the Modules automated with dependencies to a Windows System?
Even a whole download of the CPAN Repository would be a solution for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a local mirror of CPAN with `minicpan`. It's intended to distribute a copy of CPAN (or a subset of it) on media so you have it in case there is no internet available, e.g. a USB drive that you can use on a laptop while you are on an airplane so you can still install a dependency, even if it's outdated a bit.

Check out [CPAN::Mini](https://metacpan.org/release/CPAN-Mini) and the [minicpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPAN-Mini/bin/minicpan) utility on CPAN as well as [this guide on how to set up a mirror on perl.org](http://www.cpan.org/misc/how-to-mirror.html). There is [a guide on blogs.perl.org](http://blogs.perl.org/users/marc_sebastian_jakobs/2009/11/how-to-set-up-you-own-cpan-mirror.html) as well. Furthermore, [this guide in German](http://perl-howto.de/2008/06/making-your-own-cpanmini.html) is very comprehensive and has a list of related material at the bottom.

In fact, there is a whole tag [minicpan](/questions/tagged/minicpan) here on Stack Overflow. One of the very helpful reads (though not a full duplicate) is [ysth's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20315360/1331451).

Comment: I have decided not to quote any of the linked tutorials here as they are quite long.

Comment: Hi simbabque,
thank you for your reply. It looks a bit complex to create first an repository on windows were i first have to integrate perl in windows some more work and try and error. Is there no way to Download to whole repository?

Comment: How would you access it then? You can simply install an ActivePerl or a Strawberry Perl and use that. I've actually used CPAN::Mini to create  120 USB flash drives including the current latest full CPAN to give away at the German Perl Workshop as a sponsoring item for `$work`. It's super easy to make the minicpan (compared to creating an iso file and cloning that on 120 drives, that is). And getting the Perl on Windows is no problem.

Comment: @user2273214 on the other hand, have you looked at Fatpacker to bundle all your deps with your program?